# running Mathematica remotely on macs

Tags: macos, wolfram-mathematica, x11

Here is what I want to do:

I want to run Mathematica on another Mac from my Mac (both Snow Leopards).  I want to do this because the remote Mac has multiple cores/processors while my local Mac is rather shabby. I would like to have the front end still locally (i.e. the graphical interface).

What I've learned:

I used to do this type of thing from multiple Linux machines and was expecting to have similar success for Mac-to-Mac operation. However no such luck. 
The problem seems to be a display issue (front end).
Mac front end runs in Aqua while X11 is what is really needed (this is why there is no problem on Unix). While Macs have X11, for some reason Mathematica can't use it.

So how do I get around this issue?
Possible solutions that I have had to rule out are: 1. screen sharing. Not practical since someone else will be using the remote Mac on another account. Screen sharing only uses the active screen. 2. Installing Unix on the remote computer. Not possible in my situation.

Thanks.

Comment: You could start another X session (if Mac uses X) and run Mathematica via SSH from that X session.

Comment: Mathematica on OS X is not a X11 application, so this won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set up a remote kernel on the other Mac.  This is done through the **Evaluation > Kernel Configurations** menu item.  The you can set the remote kernel for a given notebook using **Evaluation > Notebook's Kernel** or globally via **Evaluation > Default Kernel**.

I haven't done this in a while, and it's sometimes useful to test things from a terminal with something like

```
ssh <user>@<remote.machine.com> </path/to/remote/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the command line kernel?  I have a script `math` which does:

```
#!/bin/bash
rlwrap /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel
```

I built rlwrap from source, but basically that tool gives you readline behaviors.  You can just do

```
ssh remote-machine /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel
```

Comment: Well, I could but I would prefer to have the front end. I know it's possible what I want to do but it's just not happening for me yet.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution, I believe, is for you to upgrade to OS X Lion. It allows simultaneous screen sharing sessions where each user can control the screen for their own account:
http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/features.html#screensharing

Comment: Yeah, I saw that feature. Unfortunately, I don't think my adviser is willing to do that. Maybe with some more coercion.

Comment: Using the remote kernel feature in Mathematica seems like a fix but it has not worked for me. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615660/mathematica-remote-kernel-on-macs