# mathematica remote kernel on macs

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to run a remote mathematica kernel between two macs.

Under Kernel Configuration Options
For kernel program I have:
/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel

The arguments of MLOpen:
-LinkMode Listen
-LinkProtocol TCPIP
-LinkOptions MLDontInteract

The launch command is:
`java` -jar `mathssh` username@xxxxxx.dynamic.uiowa.edu /usr/local/bin/math -mathlink -LinkMode
Connect -LinkProtocol TCPIP -LinkName "`linkname`" -LinkHost `ipaddress`

When i use this remote kernel (for instance 2+2 does not give a result) I get the error message:
"The kernel Thomas Machine failed to connect to the front end. (Error = MLECONNECT). You should try running the kernel connection outside the front end."

It seems that Mathematica is not even opening on the remote machine since I used "top" and do not see it running after I start the remote kernel.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried this with 8.0.1 -- here's my config (with bogus machine/user names):

[image: kernel config dialog]

In particular the `/usr/local/bin/math` looks suspicious.  You generally shouldn't need to use the advanced settings.

Drop to a command line and try:

```
ssh username@xxxxxx.dynamic.uiowa.edu /usr/local/bin/math
```

and see if you get a Mathematica prompt and can evaluate `1+1` there.

Comment: Thanks @Brett Champion. So did it work for you? You were able to get front end on the local machine? When I do the command line like you suggest I do open Mathematica and can calculate 1+1 in the terminal. I noticed that only MathKernel is running on remote machine and not Mathematica. Shouldn't Mathematica be running there?

Comment: Yes, it worked for me, but it's a remote *kernel*.  The *frontend* is running locally on my machine.  On OS X, at least through 10.6, you can't use a graphical version of the frontend on a remote machine unless you run it as the user that is currently logged in normally.  You indicated that this wasn't an option for you.  I've read things that make me think this restriction may be lifted with 10.7, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I'm a little confused. My situation is such that the remote account I'm using is logged out and someone else is logged in with a different account. So I don't want any front end on the remote machine (am I correct that front end means the graphical interface that normally pops up when using Mathematica?). But I do want front end locally. If I understand you correctly, you did exactly what I want to do. That gives me hope! Btw I am using 10.6.8.

Comment: Oh, one more thing. Might there be some settings on the remote machine that I need to have set to make this work?

Comment: Right.  The GUI is running on my machine, but the calculation are running on another machine (which is currently being actively used by a co-worker.)  Both machines are running 10.6.8.  If you can use the kernel remotely from the command line (the `ssh ...` check), then I can't think of a reason it wouldn't work from Mathematica.  If you continue to have problems, I'd suggest emailing support@wolfram.com.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Still no luck for me. I believe Mathematica is talking to the remote Mac since when I first run the remote kernel I get an Authenticity of host RSA fingerprint error. But I never am asked a password for some reason. I will send an e-mail to Wolfram now.